# Kafka Topic and Partition allocation for consumer

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-topic, sarama

I just started working on kafka, I need to develop a consumer client using sarama go pkg, the client is supposed to be a part of consumer group, and is needed to read from two topic A and B, client needs to read from some partitions of topic A allocated to it by any balance strategy and for B it needs to read from all partition (B is kinda like brodcast topic).

Workflow:

- consumer group xx.
- I have two topic A and B with 6 partition [0,1,2...5] each.
- I have two consumer C1 and C2 in xx, data should be read in such a way:
  C1 reads from A:[0,1,2] and from B:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6] 
  C2 reads from A:[3,4,5] and from B:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

***note: in case an new client is added the partition in A should be rebalance and all partition in B should be read.***

I tried implementing my custom balance strategy but failed, Please let me know if this can be done and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For any consumer in the same consumer group, it is not possible for multiple to be listening to any overlapping partitions. In other words, listening to all partitions of topic B cannot be done unless you move C2 consumer to its own unique group, regardless of the rebalancing strategy for consumer groups for topic A.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement both Partition Consumer and Group Consumer in your service.

**1. Group Consumer**

Use Group Consumer to consume messages from topic "A". You can implement `ConsumerGroup` interface in Sarama library. Both your consumers "C1" and "C2" need to subscribe to topic "A" as a group (using the same client ID).

**2. Partition Consumer**

Use Partition consumers to consume messages in topic "B". Use `Consumer` interface in Sarama library for this. "C1" and "C2" need to subscribe to all partitions in starting up and also after a rebalance.